# How to minimize space after line break?

Tags: html, css

I made  list, made line height bigger and now when i'm testing responsiveness, i see a big gap after line break in each li if i shrink the site to iphone x size or so.

i just want to know if it's possible to minimize this line break with my code.
i tried margin 0 but it doesn't work.
i'm new to coding so thanks in advance

```css
* {
    transition: all .1s ease-in;
}

html,body{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0; /* Space from this element (entire page) and others*/
    padding: 0; /*space from content and border*/
    border: solid #EEEEEE;
    border-width: thick;
    overflow:hidden;
    display:block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* header */
h1, h3 {
    margin: 0px;
}

.titles {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #4B4F55;
    color: #D07772; 
    font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
    padding: 5px 0px;
    
}

body {
    background-color: #3C3F44;
    
}


ul {
   padding: 0px;
   list-style-type: none;
   margin:  100px auto;
   color: #D4D6E0;  
   font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
   font-size: 20px;
   font-weight: normal; 
   width: 50%;
}

/* coloring li */
ul li:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #848099;
}
/* coloring li */
ul li:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #797691;
}

ul li {
    /* overflow: auto; */
   line-height: 40px;
}

ul li:hover  {
    background-color: #615E75;
    border: solid 0.5px;
    border-color: #D4D6E0; 
}

li, label {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
}

ul li:active {
    background-color: #D78F8D;
}

/* hiding checkbox */
input[type="checkbox"] {
    display: none;
}

/* Custom checkbox */
.checkmark  {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 17px;
  width: 17px;
  background-color: #eee;
  margin: 12px 0 0 5px;
}

span.list-name {
    margin-left: 30px;
}

/* custom checkmark */
 input:checked + span.checkmark {
 background-color: #4C4F55;
 content: url(https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/2107/2107638.svg);
}

.title-after {
 font-size: 14px;
}
  /* main text line-through */
.li-item input:checked ~ .list-name {
 text-decoration: line-through;
  }
   
footer {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #4B4F55;
    color: #D07772; 
    font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 40px;
    opacity: 20%;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 300px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: auto
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" initial-scale="1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style/main.css">
        <title> Shopping list</title>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <header>
            <div class="titles"> 
                <h1>CSS Shopping List</h1>
                <h3>Let's go to the mall</h3> 
            </div>              
        </header>
                <ul>
                   <li class="li-item">              
                        <label class="pickles">
                            <input type="checkbox"> 
                            <span class="checkmark"></span>  
                            <span class="list-name">A lot of pickles
                                 <span class="title-after"> (the next lessons of CSS)</span> 
                            </span>                          
                        </label>
                    </li>
                     <li class="li-item">
                         <label class="apples">
                            <input type="checkbox">
                            <span class="checkmark"></span>  
                            <span class="list-name"> 10 apples 
                                <span class="title-after"> (for more CSS manipulation) </span>                         
                            </span>
                        </label>
                    </li>
                    <li class="li-item">
                        <label class="oranges">
                            <input type="checkbox">
                            <span class="checkmark"></span>   
                            <span class="list-name"> 20 oranges 
                                <span class="title-after"> (because they are awesome)</span>
                                </span>
                        </label>
                    </li>
                    <li class="li-item">
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox">
                            <span class="checkmark"></span>   
                            <span class="list-name">13 plates
                                <span class="title-after">  (hmmm... they always dissapear)</span>
                                </span>                            
                        </label>
                    </li>
                    <li class="li-item">
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox">
                            <span class="checkmark"></span>  
                            <span class="list-name">15 bentos</span>
                        </label>
                    </li>
                    <li class="li-item">
                        <label class="sake">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="sake">
                            <span class="checkmark"></span> 
                            <span class="list-name"> Bottle of sake 
                                <span class="title-after"> (for my friends)</span>
                            </span>
                        </label>      
                    </li>  
                </ul>
    </body>
    <footer>
          Bon appetite
    </footer>
    
</html>
```

Comment: Use padding instead on line-height. See example here: https://jsfiddle.net/r2pjzkfg/

Comment: I tried it but then padding area is not clickable for checkmark

Comment: You can wrap the content within your li in a div with padding to keep the padding "clickable". Or simply apply the padding to label like so: https://jsfiddle.net/r2pjzkfg/1/

Answer (score 0):

Set the label to `display: flexbox`, and add padding to the label. The `.checkbox` should not be absolutely positioned, and should have `flex: 0 0 auto`, so it wouldn't shrink because of the flexbox.

Note: In this solution, the text would wrap, but won't go under the checkbox.

```css
* {
  transition: all .1s ease-in;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  /* Space from this element (entire page) and others*/
  padding: 0;
  /*space from content and border*/
  border: solid #EEEEEE;
  border-width: thick;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/* header */

h1,
h3 {
  margin: 0px;
}

.titles {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #4B4F55;
  color: #D07772;
  font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
  padding: 5px 0px;
}

body {
  background-color: #3C3F44;
}

ul {
  padding: 0px;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 100px auto;
  color: #D4D6E0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: normal;
  width: 50%;
}


/* coloring li */

ul li:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #848099;
}


/* coloring li */

ul li:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #797691;
}

ul li:hover {
  background-color: #615E75;
  border: solid 0.5px;
  border-color: #D4D6E0;
}

li,
label {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
}

label {
  display: flex;
  align-items: baseline;
  padding: 10px;
}

ul li:active {
  background-color: #D78F8D;
}


/* hiding checkbox */

input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}


/* Custom checkbox */

.checkmark {
  display: block;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  height: 17px;
  width: 17px;
  background-color: #eee;
}

span.list-name {
  margin-left: 10px;
}


/* custom checkmark */

input:checked+span.checkmark {
  background-color: #4C4F55;
  content: url(https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/2107/2107638.svg);
}

.title-after {
  font-size: 14px;
}


/* main text line-through */

.li-item input:checked~.list-name {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

footer {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #4B4F55;
  color: #D07772;
  font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 40px;
  opacity: 20%;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 300px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: auto
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" initial-scale="1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style/main.css">
  <title> Shopping list</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="titles">
      <h1>CSS Shopping List</h1>
      <h3>Let's go to the mall</h3>
    </div>
  </header>
  <ul>
    <li class="li-item">
      <label class="pickles">
<input type="checkbox"> 
<span class="checkmark"></span>  
  <span class="list-name">A lot of pickles
  <span class="title-after"> (the next lessons of CSS)</span> 
</span>                          
</label>
    </li>
    <li class="li-item">
      <label class="apples">
<input type="checkbox">
<span class="checkmark"></span>  
<span class="list-name"> 10 apples 
    <span class="title-after"> (for more CSS manipulation) </span>                         
</span>
</label>
    </li>
    <li class="li-item">
      <label class="oranges">
<input type="checkbox">
<span class="checkmark"></span>   
<span class="list-name"> 20 oranges 
    <span class="title-after"> (because they are awesome)</span>
    </span>
</label>
    </li>
    <li class="li-item">
      <label>
<input type="checkbox">
<span class="checkmark"></span>   
<span class="list-name">13 plates
    <span class="title-after">  (hmmm... they always dissapear)</span>
    </span>                            
</label>
    </li>
    <li class="li-item">
      <label>
<input type="checkbox">
<span class="checkmark"></span>  
<span class="list-name">15 bentos</span>
</label>
    </li>
    <li class="li-item">
      <label class="sake">
<input type="checkbox" id="sake">
<span class="checkmark"></span> 
<span class="list-name"> Bottle of sake 
    <span class="title-after"> (for my friends)</span>
</span>
</label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>
<footer>
  Bon appetite
</footer>

</html>
```